# Create Stored Procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a school task and i'm wondering why it's not working.
My task: Write a statement for a stored procedure, which will give back all the projects the Mitarbeiter took part and the hours he/she spent on each project. (We should use CREATE FUNCTION)

[image]

My Solution:

```
CREATE TYPE ty_projects_hours AS (Projekte VARCHAR, Stunden INTEGER);

CREATE FUNCTION projects_hours (Mitarbeiter_Mail VARCHAR) 
RETURN SETOF ty_projects_hours AS
'SELECT P_ID, Stunden FROM Projektteilnehmer;';

SELECT * FROM projects_hours (mauter@ubprojekte.de);
```

-> So if i

```
SELECT * FROM projects_hours
```

i type the mail in the brackets to find the Mitarbeiter.

pgAdmin says: No language given.

Comment: `CREATE TYPE` is a postgreSQL thing, not a MySQL thing. You may want to [edit] your tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"No language given*"

What the error message says: you are missing a `language sql`. You also don't need to create a type for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION projects_hours (Mitarbeiter_Mail VARCHAR) 
  RETURN table (projekte varchar, stunden integer)
AS
'SELECT P_ID, Stunden FROM Projektteilnehmer;'
language sql; --<<< this was missing
```

But you are not using the parameter, so I think you meant:

```
CREATE FUNCTION projects_hours (mitarbeiter_mail VARCHAR) 
  RETURN table (projekte varchar, stunden integer)
AS
$$
  SELECT P_ID, Stunden 
  FROM Projektteilnehmer
  WHERE teilnehmer = mitarbeiter_mail;
$$ 
language sql;
```

Then call it with a proper string parameter which needs single quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects_hours('mauter@ubprojekte.de');
```

Comment: Thanks! It was only the missing lanuage! :D